# git push origin HEAD и git puill origin HEAD

Tags: git

Как-то раз на работе я закосячил одной командой: `git pull origin HEAD`.

До сих пор не могу найти в Интернетах, почему.

В репозитории 2 ветки. Я работал над второй веткой, нужно было перетянуть изменения из неё же, но удаленной. Команда `git pull origin HEAD` мне показалась вполне логичным решением, ведь `HEAD` (поправьте, если хоть в чем-то ошибся) указывает на коммит текущей ветки. То есть содержит инфу о том, что это за ветка.

В итоге эта команда вмержила ветку `master`, чего очень не нужно было делать.

И это довольно странное поведение, ведь команда `git push origin HEAD` отправляет изменения не куда-то там в какую-то левую ветку (мастер или не мастер), а в определенно нужную.

Так вот. Почему это произошло? Как объяснил мне коллега, команда `git pull origin HEAD` берет все ветки и сливает их в текущую. Если это так, то чем такое поведение Гита обусловлено?

Answer (score 2):

На удалённом репозитории `HEAD` ссылается на дефаултную ветку, которая будет выкачиваться при клонировании репозитория. Обычно это как раз `master`.

А вот про все ветки я что-то не верю.

Comment: Я тож не поверил. Слишком много логики для такой команды.

Comment: То есть если я пишу `git fetch origin HEAD`, то я беру HEAD удаленного репозитория (который дефолтный, он же, как всегда, master)?

Comment: Таким образом команда `git pull origin HEAD` подразделяется на 2 такие команды, которые идут друг за другом: `git fetch origin HEAD`,  `git merge origin/HEAD`, и туда по факту подставляется мастер? Всё так?